# xCode4 - How to create a font selection capability like iBooks or Kindle?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, fonts, ios5

I am developing an app where I would like to offer users the capability to style the pages to their preference.

One preference is fonts (type face and size). I can create this using simple preferences, but is there something magic that iBooks or Kindle (and now - Noteability.app) does? (see images)

Thanks.

[image: Noteability![]

[image: Kindle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. iBooks just shows a `UITableView` when you tap the `aA` button. The second row shows two buttons to change the font size. I guess they store the current font size in some variable and when one of the buttons is tapped, they updated it, very simple. Taping `fonts` just shows some more rows with the available fonts. When one is selected, the `UITextView` (or whatever custom class they use) is updated.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, as I was typing the question and gathering images, I kinda saw that these were just tableViews. I guess when the content is a long single text block, it's easy to change fonts. I have a complex table view where the fonts must be changed in - probably - 20 places in order to effect a single preference (cells, headers, tableView, rootView, detailView, etc). But, thank you for answering anyway, and I'll close this question out..